# Any helpful resources to build with the Laravel framework and php?

Tags: decentralized-applications, lucid, mesh, payment

There are good libraries for Javascript frameworks to build dApp like Meshjs, Lucid, etc.

I'm new to PHP and the Laravel framework.

1. Is it possible to integrate those JavaScript libraries, with the Laravel framework?
2. Or, are there any dedicated packages or tools available for Laravel framework to build dApp?

The use case is to connect a wallet and send payments.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've also used Laravel in the past and did a combination of Cardano Serialization Lib (or now Multiplatform Lib) in Javascript.

So on clientside I mainly used JS to interact with:

- CIP30 webwallet connections / signTx or getUtxo's or signData, etc
- CSL/CML to serialize transactions which are submitted through the client's wallet

For any blockchain queries I used a combination of :

- Blockfrost API
- DB-sync connection

Hope this helps!